# how to creating a separator line which is always in the middle (center)

Tags: html, css

I have two `div` that are next to each other. which one of them has `float: left` and another has `float: right`. the `div`s are contained a word. The number of character of this word is changing. Now I need to a separator line for separating them, something like this: `|`.

Here is my **structure**:

html:

```
<div id="main">
<div class="left"><?php echo $word1;?></div>
<div class="right"><?php echo $word2;?></div>
</div>
```

It should be noted that the size of `main` is fixed. (e.g. `200px`)

css:

```
<style>
 #main {width: 200px;}
 .left {float: left}
 .right {float: right}
</style>
```

**Example1:**

```
// Initialization
<?php
$word1 = 'foo';
$word2 = 'bar';
?>

// output
+---------------200px------------------+
|foo                                bar|
+--------------------------------------+
```

**Example2:**

```
// Initialization
<?php
$word1 = 'stack';
$word2 = 'overflow';
?>

// output
+---------------200px------------------+
|stack                         overflow|
+--------------------------------------+
```

Now I need to a separator line like this: `|` between them. It should be noted that ***I want that this line always be in the middle (center)***. I want this output:

```
// output
+---------------200px------------------+
|stack ---N px--- | ---N px--- overflow|
+--------------------------------------+
```

And for more clarification: **(Example3)**

```
// Initialization
<?php
$word1 = 'hello world';
$word2 = 'test';
?>

// output
+---------------200px------------------+
|hello world --N px--- | --N px--- test|
+--------------------------------------+
```

or

```
+---------------200px------------------+
|hello world           |           test|
+--------------------------------------+
```

How can I do that ? I tried it with `border-left` (for right side div) and conversely but did not work. also I tried it with `&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;` but did not work.

[here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/yg29vz9q/) is my fiddle with `border` and `padding`.
How can I do that ?

Comment: what do you mean border left didn;t work? post a fiddle of what you tried

Comment: @RachelGallen I mean is if I use of border as separator line, it will not be center all the time.

Comment: Do need the line to be a border? Or are you using an image? or can it even be the "|" character?

Comment: @AndreaJessup It can be anything, border is fine, this "|" character is fine.  I just want a separator line that always be center.

Comment: @RachelGallen check out my update.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ch3zy69u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're ok with just using the "|" character to separate the divs, this requires just a small amount of CSS and HTML changes.  Note: the order of the divs does matter - that separator has to be last:

Your HTML:

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="left"><?php echo $word1;?></div>
  <div class="right"><?php echo $word2;?></div>
  <div class="center">|</div>
</div>
```

The new CSS:

```
    .left
    {
        float: left;
    }

    .center
    {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .right
    {
        float: right;
    }
```

[Here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/yg29vz9q/1/) is the fiddle.